# Killian, Ink Duelist; Target "Creature"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Something I wondered about [Killian, Ink Duelist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=513689) was how this card's cost-reduction ability interacted with spells that interact with creature *cards or spells* and not creature *permanents.*

Spells like [Empyrial Armor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382923) and [Crib Swap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=489685) can both target a creature permanent on the battlefield which allows these spells to cost less to cast if Killian is on the battlefield under your control while casting and targeting a creature with those spells.

However, something like [Animate Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413620) targets a "creature card in a graveyard," so is it implied that with Killian on the battlefield under your control, Animate Dead costs less to cast because it targets a "creature" anyway?

How would Killian interact with [Venser, Shaper Savant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=509461) regarding  returning a target spell to its owner's hand if the spell targeted is a creature spell?

Does a spell targeting a creature not have to be a permanent on the battlefield for the spell to cost less with Killian out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Killian's ability only affects spells targeting creature permanents.**

[Rule 109.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Object) says

> If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

Killian's ability refers to "creatures", which is a card type, without using any of the specified words, so it means creature permanents.